# Exception running MRBenchmark on hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop

I have set up hadoop in a distributed manner and it is working correctly. I have been trying to run the mrbenchmark as per the instructions given in http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2011/04/09/benchmarking-and-stress-testing-an-hadoop-cluster-with-terasort-testdfsio-nnbench-mrbench/

However I get the following exception,

    `hadoop jar build/hadoop-0.20-test.jar mrbench -numRuns 1 -maps 2 -reduces 1 -inputLines 1 -inputType ascending
    MRBenchmark.0.0.2
    14/03/16 21:37:03 INFO conf.ClientConfigurationUtil: Client configuration lookup disabled/failed. Using default configuration
    14/03/16 21:37:04 INFO mapred.MRBench: creating control file: 1 numLines, ASCENDING sortOrder
    14/03/16 21:37:04 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    14/03/16 21:37:04 INFO mapred.MRBench: created control file: /benchmarks/MRBench/mr_input/input_1714244267.txt
    14/03/16 21:37:04 INFO fs.FileSystem: File /benchmarks/MRBench is being deleted only through Trash.
    Moved to trash: /benchmarks/MRBench
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:514)
        at java.util.Properties.setProperty(Properties.java:161)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:476)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.setJar(JobConf.java:474)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MRBench.runJobInSequence(MRBench.java:180)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MRBench.run(MRBench.java:289)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:68)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:82)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MRBench.main(MRBench.java:211)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
        at org.apache.hadoop.test.AllTestDriver.main(AllTestDriver.java:87)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)`

I am using Hadoop version 20.2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including the parameters -jar and specifying an example jar solved my problem ( I mentioned the mrbenchmark jar again).

eg.  hadoop jar build/hadoop-0.20-test.jar mrbench -numRuns 1 -maps 2 -reduces 1 -inputLines 1 -inputType ascending -jar build/hadoop-0.20-test.jar

Even though the Benchmark states that the argument -jar is initialized to the current jar, this is not the case. The -jar argument has to be specified.